# umbraco, get param from url or set session

Tags: url, parameters, xslt, session-variables, umbraco

I have in umbraco

- a content tree with pages to be displayed in navigation and frontend
- a storage folder with different kinds of records

I would like to have a single page in Umbraco in the content tree, that can display info from just one record stored in the storage folder.

Example:
Storage folder contain several doc-types of animal

In content tree I can do different kinds of listing by category (four legs, predator, cutly etc.). When clicking any animal from any list I would like to go to the same page plus a parameter:
http://mysite/animal.aspx?showthis=1254 (that's the lion)

Can that be done? I cannot find anything about hos Umbraco/XSLT can read a parameter from the url.

If not possible can it be done with setting a session in xslt?

Br. Anders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to obtain the query parameter in xslt like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RequestQueryString('showthis')"/>
```